# Testing a Java method's execution time and memory consumption via JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I want to profile how a method's execution time and memory consumption scale depending on the method's parameters. So far, I have come up with testing the method via JUnit and running several tests for different sets of parameters (e.g. using [JUnit Theories](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theories.html)). In order to abstract from overhead due to setting up tests etc. the time is calculated by a difference in `System.currentTimeMillis` right before and after the step I am interested in. This seems somewhat hacky, is there a more natural way to do this?

I would furthermore like to see how memory consumption behaves with different parameters. JVisualVM comes to mind, but is there a more elegant way to automatically get what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) java benchmark framework.

> JMH is a Java harness for building, running, and analysing
>   nano/micro/milli/macro benchmarks written in Java and other languages
>   targetting the JVM.

Comment: I don't think it covers the memory aspect of the question, does it?

Comment: Memory usage also can be covered, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640804/count-metrics-with-jmh